# What is the preferred tag: mempool, memory-pool or txpool?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I noticed when asking a regular question that there's both a `mempool` (used 2 times) and `memory-pool` tag (used 5 times)? I went with `memory-pool`, but what is actually the preferred one? Shouldn't one of them be retagged?

Answer (score 5):

Good question. I personally like `memory-pool` but have no strong feelings in favor of one over the other and noticed that [Bitcoin SE](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mempool) uses the `mempool` tag.

[Ethereum SE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/txpool) uses `txpool` so there appears to be no StackExchange consensus yet.

For now I suggested a [synonym](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)

**update**: based on the comments below I now favor `txpool` which as user36303 informs us is used in the Monero source code

Comment: Well, don't compare apples and oranges. The ethereum term is txpool and the Bitcoin term is mempool. What's the monero term? memory pool or mempool?

Comment: txpool :) placeholder for stupid length check

Comment: @user36303 I have no objection to txpool either. Do you think that there is consensus among the dev team? Moneropedia not list either term yet

Comment: I was only going by the source code which calls it tx_pool.

Comment: @user36303 the source code seems like the best source to me! Does anyone have an objection to adopting txpool (or tx-pool) as the preferred tag?

Comment: @user36303 I like txpool

Comment: I'm used to seeing mempool, but I'd vote for txpool as it is self-explanatory.