# Tag synonym suggestions

Tags: discussion

Currently there are [6 different tag synonyms](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) waiting for approval. Please share your approval (or disapproval) of them.

In particular more feedback is requested for [this question](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/q/95/11). Which do you link is the best "master" synonym between the following?

1. `memory-pool` most common tag of the three so far
2. `mempool`
3. `txpool` used in Monero source code (as tx_pool)

If your current [privilege level](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) allows you do do so [please vote](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) on the current suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussion with 2quick-4u we are consent that this is a good move. I approved your suggestions.